# How to get Image Filename and Tag of images in photos album?

Tags: iphone, ios, alassetslibrary

Is there a way to get the image file name and tag of images in the photo album?

I'm using `ALAssetsLibrary` and still scratching...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALAssetRepresentation *AssetRepObj = [AssetObj defaultRepresentation];
NSString *FileName = [AssetRepObj filename];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can copy the `ALAssetLibrary` object into an array (or better in a Local DB). Make objects of `ALAsset` to display and give them tag (depending on array index).

Or otherwise if you still wish to continue with the Image names. you can obtain them from the `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL`.  Try the substring function to get the name (hint: mostly it is before the `&ext`, also you can get the extension of file.)